# mysqli error - bind_param: number of variables doesn't match

Tags: php, mysqli, bindparam

I am getting the following error but I have counted things over and over again and everything appears to be fine. Anyone have any ideas on it ?

Error:

> **Warning**:  mysqli_stmt::bind_param() [mysqli-stmt.bind-param]: Number of
>   variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in
>   **/home/ambnews/public_html/invoice/response.php** on line
>   **204**

Code:

```
// invoice customer information
    // billing
    $customer_name = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['customer_name']); // customer name
    $customer_email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['customer_email']); // customer email
    $customer_address_1 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['customer_address_1']); // customer address
    $customer_address_2 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['customer_address_2']); // customer address
    $customer_town = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['customer_town']); // customer town
    $customer_county = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['customer_county']); // customer county
    $customer_postcode = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['customer_postcode']); // customer postcode
    $customer_phone = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['customer_phone']); // customer phone number

    //shipping
    $customer_name_ship = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['customer_name_ship']); // customer name (shipping)
    $customer_address_1_ship = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['customer_address_1_ship']); // customer address (shipping)
    $customer_address_2_ship = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['customer_address_2_ship']); // customer address (shipping)
    $customer_town_ship = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['customer_town_ship']); // customer town (shipping)
    $customer_county_ship = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['customer_county_ship']); // customer county (shipping)
    $customer_postcode_ship = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['customer_postcode_ship']); // customer postcode (shipping)

    $query = "INSERT INTO store_customers (
                    name,
                    email,
                    address_1,
                    address_2,
                    town,
                    county,
                    postcode,
                    phone,
                    name_ship,
                    address_1_ship,
                    address_2_ship,
                    town_ship,
                    county_ship,
                    postcode_ship
                ) VALUES (
                    '".$customer_name."',
                    '".$customer_email."',
                    '".$customer_address_1."',
                    '".$customer_address_2."',
                    '".$customer_town."',
                    '".$customer_county."',
                    '".$customer_postcode."',
                    '".$customer_phone."',
                    '".$customer_name_ship."',
                    '".$customer_address_1_ship."',
                    '".$customer_address_2_ship."',
                    '".$customer_town_ship."',
                    '".$customer_county_ship."',
                    '".$customer_postcode_ship."'
                );
            ";

    /* Prepare statement */
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
    if($stmt === false) {
      trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $query . ' Error: ' . $mysqli->error, E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    print_r($stmt->bind_param(
        'sssssssissssss',
        $customer_name,$customer_email,$customer_address_1,$customer_address_2,$customer_town,$customer_county,$customer_postcode,
        $customer_phone,$customer_name_ship,$customer_address_1_ship,$customer_address_2_ship,$customer_town_ship,$customer_county_ship,$customer_postcode_ship));

    /* Bind parameters. TYpes: s = string, i = integer, d = double,  b = blob */
    $stmt->bind_param(
        'sssssssissssss',
        $customer_name,$customer_email,$customer_address_1,$customer_address_2,$customer_town,$customer_county,$customer_postcode,
        $customer_phone,$customer_name_ship,$customer_address_1_ship,$customer_address_2_ship,$customer_town_ship,$customer_county_ship,$customer_postcode_ship);

    /* Execute statement */
    $stmt->execute();

    if($stmt->execute()){
        //if saving success
        echo json_encode(array(
            'status' => 'Success',
            'message' => 'Customer has been created successfully!'
        ));
    } else {
        // if unable to create invoice
        echo json_encode(array(
            'status' => 'Error',
            'message' => 'There has been an error, please try again.'
            // debug
            //'message' => 'There has been an error, please try again.<pre>'.$mysqli->error.'</pre><pre>'.$query.'</pre>'
        ));
    }

    //close database connection
    $mysqli->close();
```

Comment: you putted values already in your query. then again used bind_param. that's not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take a look at the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php):

1. You should not escape your values when you use a prepared statement as you will be adding literal backslashes in your data.
2. You should not inject your variables in the query but use placeholders (question marks in mysqli) instead. These are bound to your values.

So your query would be:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO store_customers (
                name,
                email,
                // etc.
            ) VALUES (
                ?,
                ?,
                // etc.
            );
        ";
```

And you bind your values:

```
$stmt->bind_value(
    'sssssssissssss',
    $_POST['customer_name'],
    $_POST['customer_email'],
    // etc.
);
```

Note that I am using `bind_value()` instead of `bind_param()` as this seems to be used once only so there is no need to bind parameters, you can bind the values directly. It should not make a difference though.

Comment: Im really new to this so not really sure if i'm honest. how should i best do this? thanks for your time.

Comment: @James I have added an example.

Comment: ahh yea i just done the ?,?,?,? part and worked fine, so i dont need to escape _POST? will they be secure in bind and prevent sql injections that way like you done? thanks for your help.

Comment: @James No, you should not do that, you will pollute your data with backslashes. The prepared query and bound parameters will prevent sql injection.

Comment: Is it ok to have $customer_name = $_POST['customer_name'] and then pass $customer_name into bind? its only as im updating a script and sometimes the variable is used further down

Comment: Great! thanks for confirming :) I have another function that currently does a multi_query and read a few things that not possible with prepare / bind_param is this right? i can create a new issue if your able to help as im sure i will need it on  that one haha